# VBA System.Collections.Queue

Tags: vba, stack, queue

I just discovered [here](http://analystcave.com/excel-vba-dictionary-arrays-and-other-data-structures/#The_VBA_Queue) the 'built-in' `Stacks` and `Queues` available from VBA. The way it's written, I can't see the properties and methods of the `Queue` object.

```
Dim queue As Object
Set queue = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue") 'Create the Queue

queue.Enqueue "Hello"   'VBE does not show the available properties and methods
```

So my question is: is there a reference I can use that will allow me to have early binding and benefit from the VBE autocomplete ? Something like:

```
Dim queue As System.Collections.Queue   'not working
```

Comment: There's no built-in `Stacks` and `Queues` available from VBA. Those are COM objects from the .Net framework which may be missing or unavailable depending on the setup. You can add `mscorelib.dll` to view the interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Stack` and `Queue` are COM objects from the .Net framework, they cannot be used with early binding. (as mentioned by @Florent B. in the comments).

However, if you need to see the properties of the COM object, you can always take a look at the MSDN site (it is quite explicit there): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx

Or open a Visual Studio and check from there, the IntelliSense. Pretty much anything written there works:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
    Dim myArr  As Variant        
    With CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")
        .Clear
        .Enqueue (1)
        .Enqueue (2)
        myArr = .toArray
    End With
    Debug.Print myArr(1)        
End Sub
```